# two dimensional array in c, reversing and storing a sentence

Tags: c, string

Hey I'm really new to programming and having trouble with arrays. Can someone help me with this project. "c programming a modern approach: modify a program that reverses the words of a sentence so that it stores the words in a two dimensional char array as it reads the sentence, with each row of the array storing a single word. assume that the sentence contains no more than 30 words and no word is more than 20 characters long. Be sure to store a null character at the end of each word so that it can be treated as a string"
(also i don't get what its saying about the null character).
here's my try but it's not working. i think i'm close though.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_SENTENCE_LEN 80

#define SENTENCE_MAX 30

#define WORD_MAX 20
int main(void)
{
  char ch, sentence[MAX_SENTENCE_LEN] = {' '}, terminator = '.';
  int n, i, j, start, finish;

  printf("Enter a sentence: ");
  for (n = 1; n < MAX_SENTENCE_LEN; n++) {
    ch = getchar();
    if (ch == '.' || ch == '?' || ch == '!') {
      terminator = ch;
      break;
    }
    sentence[n] = ch;
  }

  printf("Reversal of sentence:");
  finish = n;
  for (start = finish - 1; start >= 0; start--) {
    if (sentence[start] == ' ') {
      for (i = start; i < finish; i++)
        putchar(sentence[i]);
      finish = start;
    }
    {

int sentence[SENTENCE_MAX][WORD_MAX];
int word[30][20];
    for (i=0; i< SENTENCE_MAX;i++){
        for (j=0; j<WORD_MAX; j++)
            sentence[i][j]=-1;
            }
}
  }
  printf("%c\n", terminator);

  return 0;}
```

i wrote a new code which i think is closer to what i want but it still won't run. do i have a faulty compiler or what? 
anyway here's the new code

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define N 100

int main (void)

{
    char sentence[N][N], ch, termChar;
    int i = 0, l = 0, count = 0;
    int j = 0, k, start, finish, word;

    printf("enter a sentence: ");

    while (ch = getchar())
    {
        sentence[i][l++]= ch;
    if (ch == ' ')
        {
            sentence[i][l] = '\0';
            i++;
            l = 0;
            count++;
        }

        if (ch == '.' || ch == '!' || ch == '?')
        { 
                sentence[i][l-1]= ' ';
                sentence[i][l]= '\0';
                termChar = ch;
                count ++;
                break;
        }
    }

    for(i=count ; i>=0; i--)
        printf("%s ", sentence[i]);
    printf("%c\n", termChar);
    return 0; 

    }
```

Comment: So, what is the problem?  It runs perfectly for me. (except you are missing the last `}` in your posted code.)

Comment: This sounds like it's for a class; you'd be better served by asking your teacher if that's the case.

Comment: Why are you using `int[][]`, don't you want `char[][]`?

Comment: Also, read this wiki on the [null terminator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string) that your writeup mentions.

Comment: I'll just pick a random book off my shelf here to look up more info... Oh, wait, there's no chapter 8 in this book, and thus no project 14 associated with chapter 8....

Answer (score 3):

Your code worked perfectly in my environment (Windows, C99 compiler, 32bit build).  I entered a short sentence, and it reversed it:

[image]

***Regarding***:  *i don't get what its saying about the null character*

a C string is defined by a null character: \0, at the end of a char array. example char string[]="word" looks like: |w|o|r|d|\0| in memory.

Without the `\0`, it would simply be a char array, but not a string, and would therefore not be useable in any of the string functions such as `strcpy()`, `strlen()`, etc.

By the way, `sentence` creation and initialization:

```
  char sentence[MAX_SENTENCE_LEN] = {' '};
```

Does not guarantee contents for the entire length of the char array.
***This may be the reason your environment is not running your code, while my environment does.*** 
Depending on compiler, OS, and other random factors, `sentence` could be filled with anything.  So, if your code is not running on your machine, it is likely that you just need to initialize `sentence` to `\0`.  Replace that line with these:

```
  char sentence[MAX_SENTENCE_LEN]; //create 
  memset(sentence, 0 ,MAX_SENTENCE_LEN); //zero all memory
  sentence[0]=' '; //set first char to a space (' '). (not sure why)
```

Also by chance, if the user input results in string length == MAX_SENTENCE_LEN, then your program will crash as there is only enough room in `sentence` for MAX_SENTENCE_LEN-1 + `\0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_SENTENCE_LEN 80
#define SENTENCE_MAX 30
#define WORD_MAX 20

int main(void){
  char ch, sentence[MAX_SENTENCE_LEN] = {' '}, terminator = '.';
  int n, i, j, start, finish;

  char word[SENTENCE_MAX][WORD_MAX+1];
  int wc=0, wcc=0;

  printf("Enter a sentence: ");
  for (n = 1; n < MAX_SENTENCE_LEN; n++) {
    ch = getchar();
    if (ch == '.' || ch == '?' || ch == '!') {
      terminator = ch;
      break;
    } else if(ch != ' '){
      word[wc][wcc++] = ch;
    } else if(ch == ' '){//this is assumed to be one space between words.
      word[wc++][wcc] = '\0';//null character
      wcc = 0;
    }
    sentence[n] = ch;
  }
  word[wc++][wcc] = '\0';

  printf("Reversal of sentence:");
  finish = n;
  for (start = finish - 1; start >= 0; start--) {
    if (sentence[start] == ' ') {
      for (i = start; i < finish; i++)
        putchar(sentence[i]);
      finish = start;
    }
  }
  printf("%c\n", terminator);
  for(i=wc-1;i>=0;--i){
    printf("%s", word[i]);
    if(i>0)
      putchar(' ');
  }
  printf("%c\n", terminator);
  return 0;
}
```